# Simple Proof for Commutative Property of Multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-writing

I'm supposed to show that $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$ for a set $K:=\{s+t\sqrt2:s,t\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ to show that this set is a field.
I was going to set it up like:

Let $a, b\in K$ such that $a=s_1+t_1\sqrt2$ and $b=s_2+t_2\sqrt2$.
Then $a\cdot b =(s_1+t_1\sqrt2)\cdot(s_2+t_2\sqrt2)$.
Then I would use the FOIL method and multiply them out:
$a\cdot b = s_1s_2+s_1t_2\sqrt2+t_1\sqrt2s_2+2t_1t_2$
But then do I have to write my "method" for factoring them? Could I just write $(s_2+t_2\sqrt2)\cdot(s_1+t_1\sqrt2)$ next?

I guess I'm confused because I could just write something like $a\cdot b =(s_1+t_1\sqrt2)\cdot(s_2+t_2\sqrt2)=(s_2+t_2\sqrt2)\cdot(s_1+t_1\sqrt2) = b \cdot a$ but this seems trivially easy, like just stating that $a\cdot b = b\cdot a$.

Comment: Additionally, do I have to prove the distributive property of multiplication over addition first?

Comment: Think about what this set is a subset of. If the set it contains has this property, then the subset must too. Although, brute force will work equally well.

Comment: At some point you have to use axioms - what should you just assume? Here it's probably reasonable to assume that multiplication of integers is commutative, at the very least.

Comment: Your title mentions a "proof" for the commutative property of multiplication.  This seems fairly obvious as you've defined a subset $K$ of the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, and the operation of multiplication defined on $K$ seems to be simply the same as multiplication of real numbers (known to be commutative).  The body of the Question opens up a larger problem, where $K$ is a field.  I suggest focusing on what aspects of that problem are interesting.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but how do I know K is a subset of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @TedDesmond: If $s,t\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $s+t\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ since $s$, $t$, and $\sqrt{2}$ are all in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trivially easy. Your method is fine.  You could also say that the multiplication is commutative because $K\subseteq\mathbb R$. There is more work though to show that $K$ is a field. You need to show that it is closed under both addition and multiplication, and that the additive inverse of any member of $K$ is also in $K$.  You'll need to show the same thing for multiplicative inverse of non-zero elements.

Comment: Yep, I'm showing the other parts in a similar way. I was just wondering if I needed to include the details of the factorization after using FOIL in the proof. Also,  I assume proving the distributive property isn't necessary here? Because I am dealing with multiplication and addition of things $\in\mathbb Q$...

Comment: @Ted Pro tip: at this point in your mathematics education multiplying two binomials is hopefully trivial. You're welcome to use the FOIL method, but nobody needs to know. It's like saying you used the carrying method to add.

Answer (score 0):

What constitutes a valid "proof" depends on exactly how $K$ and the arithmetic operations on $K$ are defined and what facts you are assumed to already know.  I will assume that $K$ is defined as a subset of the real numbers (that is, $s+t\sqrt{2}$ refers to the real number $s+t\sqrt{2}$, rather than just being some formal expression), that $K$ inherits its arithmetic operations from the real numbers, and that basic properties of the real numbers are assumed to be known.  With these assumptions, your proof is fine, since all you're using is basic algebraic manipulation rules for real numbers.  In fact, even more simply, you can just invoke the fact that multiplication of real numbers is commutative, so multiplication of elements of $K$ is automatically commutative, being just a special case of multiplication of real numbers.  You can similarly use known facts about arithmetic of real numbers to prove several of the other field axioms for $K$.